# why can't I use pillow when I have pillow?

Tags: python

```
E:\python>pyota.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\pyota.py", line 6, in <module>
    import PILLOW
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PILLOW'
```

```
E:\python>pip install pillow
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (9.0.0)
```

Even if I used 'pillow' it didn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\pyota.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pillow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

Comment: Python is case sensitive, and also you have to know what the package and module names are. They **do not** always match the name that you use with `pip` in order to install the library. You need to *read the documentation* to learn the basics of how to use each new library.

Answer (score 2):

The download module is called "pillow", but the import is PIL (Python Imaging Library).  Pillow was forked from PIL as a clone, and was improved so much that it has replaced it.

```
from PIL import Image
```

or

```
import PIL
```